# SQLite in-memory database backup in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

How to get the SQLite in-memory data base backed up? I create the database in my Windows application. I want to take a database backup when I will close the application.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# SQLite Memory Stream as DB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11383775/c-sharp-sqlite-memory-stream-as-db)

Comment: What an absurd illogical question for a software engineer.   Backup => persist physically somewhere (not inmemory anymore!) , not to another RAM in another running machine!

Answer (score 11):

You want the [SQLite Online Backup API](http://www.sqlite.org/backup.html).

As far as I know, System.Data.SQLite does not support it yet, so you'll need to write some code. The System.Data.SQLite Forum contains an example: http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/forums/t/2403.aspx. As noted, when you patch System.Data.SQLite and call SQLite directly you do so at your own risk.

Comment: Documentation: "online backup API allows the contents of one database to be copied into another database file"

The question is absurd.. any "backup" will be persisted in non memory (non-ram)!

Answer (score 1):

you may try this code

```
using (var location = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=activeDb.db; Version=3;"))
using (var destination = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=backupDb.db; Version=3;"))
{
     location.Open();
     destination.Open();
     location.BackupDatabase(destination, "main", "main", -1, null, 0);
}
```

Comment: Your Answer is out of context because Question is about in-memory not file base DB

Comment: This answer is not out-of-context. The question is absurd -- as that "Software engineer' did not understand the meaning of the word physical-persistence in the context of backup.

Answer (score 0):

what about replacing the "in-memory database" with a "file based database"?

If you close the app the file will then still be there.

At program start you have to make shure that the database file is deleted.

Comment: No... actually we only want to use in memory database. That is our prime requirement.