# Is there an efficient way to snapshot in-memory sqlite database with System.Data.Sqlite?

Tags: c#, sqlite

I want to be able to go to and from a `byte[]` representation of an in-memory SQLite database. The only solution I know of right now is using `SQLiteConnection.BackupDatabase` method, which can copy an active in-memory database to another database on disk. I can then load that database with `File.ReadAllBytes`, but I find this approach terribly inefficient for my needs.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# SQLite Memory Stream as DB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11383775/c-sharp-sqlite-memory-stream-as-db)

Comment: M.Baboock It's not a duplicate, beacause the question you link to actually means HDD to be the end term storage. I do not. Meanwhile, does anyone bothers to read posts on SO anymore?

Comment: Gleno, did you ever find a solution for this?  Im looking for one too

Comment: @JasonCragun - Sort of. You can extend sqlite with virtual file systems, and someone has created such a file system that allows you to keep everything in memory. You then use the *_backup_* functions to clone your in memory database to this vfs, the memory of which you control. I found an implementation, looked through it, read the manual, and wrote my own in about a day. The implementation I found was very messy, and the one I wrote still has many issues. A benefit of this approach is that the byte[] will be a valid SQLite file, which is great for debugging, and storing data.