# How to take Sqlite database backup using C# or Sqlite query

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite

[Memory Stream as DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11383775/c-sharp-sqlite-memory-stream-as-db)

I have used code on this link which gave me errormessage that

> BackupDatabase() does not exists in
>   System.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection

Is there any Sqlite query to backup or export Sqlite database.
And then restore it again

I want to export database on one system and then import it in another system for same windows application installed on both systems.
I want to implement this activities on button click.

Comment: Which version of System.Data.SQLite are you using?

Comment: Version:- SQLite 3.8.11.1.       I have added it in mozila firefox through Addons.I think it's providing only following features Tables,view,index and triggers.The work which I am thinking about is easier in SQL server but not in Sqlite Database.

Comment: 3.8.11.1 is the version of the SQLite library itself. What is the version of the C# System.Data.SQLite package?

Comment: There is one more thing when I was studying Sqlite Database Connection I found that extension to database name included in 'source' attribute in connection string were different, like '.s3db', '.db' etc at different places in searched results on Google. But the Database I have prepared is having extension '.sqlite' which is working properly with my windows form application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System.Data.SQLite 1.0.74.0 is quite outdated.
For the backup API support, at least version 1.0.80.0 would be required, but you could just as well upgrade to a current version.

Comment: Okay I am going to try it will come back soon thanks in advance!

Comment: I upgraded System.Data.Sqlite from version 1.0.74.0 to 1.0.99.0 now BackupDatabase() method is working thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

backup database [link](https://sqlite.org/backup.html) in Sqlite [link](https://www.sqlite.org/) try this function

```
public void backup(string strDestination)
{
      using (var location = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=C:\activeDb.db; Version=3;"))
      using (var destination = new SQLiteConnection(string.Format(@"Data Source={0}:\backupDb.db; Version=3;", strDestination)))
      {
          location.Open();
          destination.Open();
          location.BackupDatabase(destination, "main", "main", -1, null, 0);
      }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The VACUUM INTO command introduced in SQLite version 3.27.0 (2019-02-07) can serve as an alternative. In addition to the backup it rebuilds the database file, repacking it into a minimal amount of disk space.

```
public void backup(string strDestination)
{
    using (var location = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=C:\activeDb.db; Version=3;"))
    {
        SQLiteCommand sqlCmd = location.CreateCommand();
        sqlCmd.CommandText = $"VACUUM INTO '{strDestination}'";
        sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
using (var destination = new System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection(string.Format("Data Source={0}\\DriversTrucksBackup.db; Version=3;", this.txtLocation.Text)))
                    {
                        da.cn.Open();
                        destination.Open();
                        da.cn.BackupDatabase(destination, "main", "main", -1, null, 0);
                        da.cn.Close();
                    }
```