# Append Byte[] data into SQLite existing File

Tags: c#, azure, sqlite, xamarin.forms

Below was actual task:-
[Download SQLite file as byte[] and use in Xamarin.Forms mobile App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47814140/i-want-to-take-backup-and-restore-of-sqlite-database-file-using-xamarin-azure-sd)

[image]

Now ,

I have 2 SQLite files with few common tables.
File A which I have stored in APK / IPA which I am restoring on App Launch into Actual SQLite DB called File C,
and for,
File B which I am downloading after user Authentication,

I am trying to Append File B Byte[] to File C,and it successfully appends the bytes but,

However I check file size by browsing the file location after appending the file its size gets increased but,

if I perform select statement on tables which are from file B I am not getting records from the table of it.

I am using FileMode.Append for APPENDING File B byte[] into File C

```
 using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.Append)))
                        {
                            byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
                            int len = 0;
                            while ((len = br.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                            {
                                bw.Write(buffer, 0, len);
                            }
                        }
```